# Prolog - binding of operators

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I am doing an exercise from 'Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence' by Ivan Bratko. The exercise says:

> Define the operators 'if', 'then', 'else' and ':=', so that the
>   following becomes a legal term:
>
> *if X > Y then Z := X else Z := Y*
>
> Choose the precedences so that 'if' will be the principal functor.

I am having trouble determining out of the operators 'then' and 'else', which one should have the lower precedence (and bind stronger). My answer to this question was:

```
:- op(900, fx, if).
:- op(800, xfx, else).
:- op(700, xfx, then).
:- op(600, xfx, :=).
```

(It is also stated in the book that the '>' operator has a precedence of 700).

I thought that 'then' would bind stronger than 'else', however the answer for this exercise states otherwise:

```
:- op(900, fx, if).
:- op(800, xfx, then).   
:- op(700, xfx, else).  
:- op(600, xfx, :=).
```

I am not sure of the rationale behind making 'else' have a lower precedence than 'then'. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider for example, with your definition:

```
?- write_canonical(if a then b else c).
if(else(then(a,b),c))
true.
```

and with the definition from the book:

```
?- write_canonical(if a then b else c).
if(then(a,else(b,c)))
true.
```

and further, with your definition:

```
?- write_canonical(if a then (if b then c) else d).
if(else(then(a,if(then(b,c))),d))
true.
```

and with the definition from the book:

```
?- write_canonical(if a then (if b then c) else d).
if(then(a,else(if(then(b,c)),d)))
true.
```

Note in particular that with your definition, `if ... then ... else`, is sometimes parsed as `if(else(...`, and sometimes as `if(then(...`!

Comment: So I just want to clarify, there is no definite correct answer for this question, since the answer will vary based on how the definition is parsed?

Comment: In my opinion, the question is ill-posed, since to correctly parse "if...then...else...", you need to define *ternary* operators, which are not available in Prolog. So, using infix and prefix operators, you at best get some ad hoc approximation, which will typically get some cases wrong or surprising.

Answer (score 0):

/*
When working on the creation of constructs requiring operators I like to start with
setting all of the operator priority's to 10'1 .

If the construct can be made to work with all of the operators at priority at 10'1 that is ideal .
Once that is established then the priority can be changed to accomodate further requirements .

For example the further requirements of `if _if_ then _then_ else _else_` 
are considerations of what should be containable in the `_if_` and the `_then_` and the `_else_` parts .

For example if that is desirable for `;` such as `if foo ; bar then baz ; qux`
then the priority will have to be greater than `10'1100` .

For example if that is desirable for `,` such as `if foo , bar then baz , qux`
then the priority will have to be greater than `10'1000` .

For example if that is desirable for `\+` such as `if \+ foo then \+ bar`
then the priority will have to be greater than `10'950` .

For example if that is desirable for `=` such as `if _foo_ = bar then _baz_ = qux`
then the priority will have to be greater than `10'700` .
Those 4 operators are the most important considerations .
*/

```
:- op(10'1,'fx','if') .
:- op(10'1,'yfx','then') .
:- op(10'1,'yfx','else') .

if _if_ then _then_ else _else_
:-
_if_ -> _then_ ; _else_
.

if _if_ then _then_
:-
if _if_ then _then_ else false
.

/* -- testing -- */

:- op(10'1,'fy','consider') .
:- op(10'1,'xfy','perform') .
:- op(10'1,'xfy','form') .
:- op(10'1,'xfy','expect') .
:- op(10'1,'xfy','actual') .
:- op(10'1,'xfy','success') .
:- op(10'1,'xfy','fail') .

consider _consider_ perform _perform_ form _form_ expect _expect_
:-
findall(_form_,(_consider_,_perform_),_actual_) ,
(
    _actual_ = _expect_ ->
    writeq((success perform _perform_)) , nl ;
    writeq((failure perform _perform_ expect _expect_ actual _actual_)) , nl
)
.

test
:-
consider
(
    (_a_ = true) ; 
    (_a_ = false)
)
perform
(
    if _a_ then (_z_ = b) else (_z_ = c)
)
form
(
    _z_
)
expect
[
    b ,
    c
]
.

test
:-
consider
(
    (_a_ = true) ; 
    (_a_ = false)
)
perform
(
    if _a_ then (_z_ = b)
)
form
(
    _z_
)
expect
[
    b
]
.

test
:-
consider
(
    (_a_ = true , _b_ = true) ;
    (_a_ = true , _b_ = false) ; 
    (_a_ = false , _b_ = true) ; 
    (_a_ = false , _b_ = false)
)
perform
(
    if _a_ then (if _b_ then (_z_ = c) else (_z_ = d)) else (_z_ = e)
)
form
(
    _z_
)
expect
[
    c ,
    d ,
    e ,
    e
]
.


    /*
    YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Sep 17 13:59:03 UTC 2016
I   ?-  \+ (test , \+ true) .
    (success)perform if _131254 then(_131271=b)else(_131271=c)
    (success)perform if _131254 then(_131268=b)
    (success)perform if _131257 then(if _131260 then(_131315=c)else(_131315=d))else(_131315=e)
    yes
    */
```